# How to change specific part of my urls to change language editing .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all urls which includes /en with /de

for example redirect http://www.example.com/en/about/ to http://www.example.com/de/about/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below rule in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Read the `mod_rewrite` manual for redirecting and rewriting URLs.

Reference : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html